# Angular Kendo chart Plot Bands after zoom in / zoom out

Tags: angular, kendo-chart, angular-kendo

I have an Angular kendo chart, where I use the "[plotBands]" attribute, in order to have some part of my chart in another color. You can see it in the attached image.

If periods are highlighted (past/current periods), then after zoom,  the chart component uses the original indexes and highlights the wrong periods.

Example 1.  (no zoom) : current period is 03-2020 (third period)

[image: One example (no zoom) : current period is 03-2020 (third period)]

After  zoom, I have this image

Example 2. With zoom: current becomes 07-2020 (the third one according to indexes).
[image: With zoom: current becomes 07-2020 (the third one according to indexes).]

So how can I  show the real selected (03-2020 third period) part and hide it after zoom?

I have tested and found that it does not work only with the "kendo-chart-category-axis".

When I set "plotbands" to "kendo-chart-value-axis"  and then zoom the chart, then it worked as expected

Comment: Please show how the options for `[plotBands]` are defined.

Comment: {color: "#0087ff"
from: 3
opacity: 0.2
to: 4}